# Android TextView.BufferType values

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Beginner Android dev here.

I am trying to set an EditText to an integer using setText(), however I am running into a little bit of trouble.

```
int min = 10; 
minEditText.setText(min + "");
```

This does not set the value of min to the EditText widget. I did a little research and found this:

```
setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)
```

Can someone walk me through how to use this, what a BufferType is, and what the best way to set the text of a EditText widget?

Much thanks.

Comment: `setText(CharSequence)` works just fine. Just make sure you call it on the correct `EditText` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *minEditText.setText(""+min);*

Answer (score 0):

To know about buffer types, follow link:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.widget.TextView.BufferType

Comment: Your link does not explain BufferTypes

Comment: The above link provides the usage of BufferType. You have to specify whether you are using a rich text, or a plain text, and you can change that dynamically. If you use Spanable, it switches to that buffer type other wise it is a plain text. In one case you provide HTML text using fromHTML method. There it is the choice of framework what buffer will be used.